# Why $watch is not working in my directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

My directive is defined as:

```js
angular.module('mainCtrl').directive('countryCtrl', ['$compile', 'Country', function($compile, Country) {

   return {
        require: "^widgetPath",
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
               selectedCountry: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, widgetPath) {

    scope.$watch("selectedCountry", function () {
                    alert ("this never get called");
                },true);
                console.log(widgetPath.model);
            }
        };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<country-ctrl id="countryCtrl" class="form-inline">
    <ui-select ng-model="selectedCountry" theme="selectize" style="{{$cat_style}}">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search ...">
    @{{$select.selected.title}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="country.title | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <p class="text-center" ng-show="loading"><span class="throbber"></span></p>

</country-ctrl>
```

When I change the selected country, `$watch` is not working, why? the scope is working correctly, as ng-show is working properly.

I am sure its some thing simple that I am missing, can some one explain?

Comment: is `$scope.model` initialized somewhere?

Comment: does your parent directive`widgetPath` created an isolated scope?

Comment: I have edited the question, I am using isolated scope, kindly check the update